# How to create a direct link to any fancybox box

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, fancybox

I need that when I click in anything that uses fancybox it generates a specific URL for that, so when I send this link to someone, it opens the specific box I want.

For example:
***fancybox.net/home***
when I click in the first image, the link still ***fancybox.net/home***
I want that when I click in the image, the URL is generated and appears in address bar like: ***fancybox.net/home/imageid=1***
so when i send ***fancybox.net/home/imageid=1*** to someone it already opens the image in the box

Thanks!

(It is like facebook photos, when you click in any photo, the photo opens in a box but the address bar changes to the image link)

**//////
UPDATE #1
//////**

I did what JFK suggested but after one hour trying i still don't know why the boxes aren't the same.

Look the diference between:

the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var thisHash = window.location.hash;
$(document).ready(function() {
if(window.location.hash) {
$(thisHash).fancybox({
    prevEffect : 'none',
    nextEffect : 'none',
    closeBtn  : false,
    arrows    : true,
    nextClick : true,
    helpers :   { 
            thumbs : {
                width  : 80,
                height : 80
            },
    title : {
            type : 'inside'
            },
    buttons : {}
                },

    afterLoad : function() {
            this.title = (this.index + 1) + ' de ' + this.group.length + '<div id="curti"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.google.com.br&amp;send=true&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=45&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:56px; height:24px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>';
            }

                }).trigger('click');
 }
 $('.fancylink').fancybox({
    prevEffect : 'none',
    nextEffect : 'none',
    closeBtn  : false,
    arrows    : true,
    nextClick : true,
    helpers :   { 
            thumbs : {
                width  : 80,
                height : 80
            },
    title : {
            type : 'inside'
            },
    buttons : {}
                },

    afterLoad : function() {
            this.title = (this.index + 1) + ' de ' + this.group.length     + '<div id="curti"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.google.com.br&amp;send=true&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=45&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:56px; height:24px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>';
            }

                });
}); // ready
</script>
```

What's wrong in that script?

Comment: Call `click()` on the link that triggers it.

Comment: I'm newbie, how may i do that?

Answer (score 14):

First you still need to have links to your images in the page that opens fancybox like:

```
<a id="image01" class="fancylink" rel="gallery" href="images/01.jpg" title="image 01">open image 01</a>
<a id="image02" class="fancylink" rel="gallery" href="images/02.jpg" title="image 02">open image 02</a>
```

... etc.

**Notice** that I am adding both an `ID` and a `class` to each anchor since the only way I have to target them via URL is through their ID ... the class will be used to open those images in fancybox in a regular way once I am on the page so I don't need to write a specific fancybox code for each ID.

then set this script on the page of reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var thisHash = window.location.hash;
$(document).ready(function() {
 if(window.location.hash) {
  $(thisHash).fancybox().trigger('click');
 }
 $('.fancylink').fancybox();
}); // ready
</script>
```

then you can provide the URL that targets each image like

```
http://mydomain.com/page.html#image01
```

or

```
http://mydomain.com/page.html#image02
```

etc.

wanna working demo?

http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/targetByID_28jan12.html#image01

http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/targetByID_28jan12.html#image02

**NOTE**: This code is for fancybox v1.3.x since you used fancybox.net as reference.

**UPDATE #1**: if you want fancybox options you need to add them in both selectors `ID` and `class` like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var thisHash = window.location.hash;
$(document).ready(function() {
 if(window.location.hash) {
  $(thisHash).fancybox({
    padding: 0
    // more API options
  }).trigger('click');
 }
 $('.fancylink').fancybox({
    padding: 0
    // more API options
 });
}); // ready
</script>
```

Of course, use the right options either for fancybox v1.3.x or 2.x

Comment: Actually i'm using fancybox v2.0.4
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Just refered fancybox.net because was an easy example to see, but it is kinda working on v2.0.4, the only problem is that when i set an ID it cancels the class.

So i got the link, but the box is unconfigured. For example: i had thumbs and helper buttons: they all disappeared when i enter by the direct link of the box. 

Also the title: i've configured font and size but it changed itself.

Comment: example (click on the first image):

http://www.hicamera.web653.uni5.net/eventodentro.html

...

http://hicamera.web653.uni5.net/eventodentro.html#image0

Comment: then you need to add the same API options as in the class selector to the script that fires fancybox from URL like $(thisHash).fancybox({padding:0 //etc }).trigger('click');

Comment: What's about using the onhashchange event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange

Comment: I wanted to ask a follow-up question to this answer.  I got this working for myself and its great, but I'm noticing that its only linking to the specific image, even if its part of a larger group of images.  How can I set this up to link directly to a specific image, but still be able to view other images within that same group?  I'm using the latest fancybox version (2.1.5).

All my links look like this:
`<a id="id01" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="folder01" href="./photos/image01.jpg" title="folder01">image01</a>`