# Assigning thumb to fancybox's url (image)

Tags: jquery, facebook, fancybox, share, thumbnails

This comes after ["Direct link to any fancybox", but with URL in address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320630/direct-link-to-any-fancybox-but-with-url-in-address-bar). Now that I managed to assign an unique url to each image of my fancybox gallery, I was wondering if by sharing e.g. image #1 url, it would outcome the correct thumb, for example, on Facebook.

I'm using the latest fancybox and jquery versions.

Here is the Javascript:

```
    var thisHash = window.location.hash;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'fade',
            nextEffect : 'fade',
            closeBtn  : true,
            arrows    : true,
            nextClick : true,
            padding : 15,
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 80,
                    height : 80
                }
            },
            beforeShow: function () {
                var id = this.element.attr("id")
                if (id) {
                    window.location.hash = id;
                }
            },
            beforeClose: function() {
                window.location.hash = "";
            }
        });

        if(thisHash) {
            $(thisHash).trigger('click');
        }
    });
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<a class="thumbs" data-fancybox-group="group1" id="image1" href="http://freeimagesarchive.com/data/media/206/1_black.jpg"><img src="http://freeimagesarchive.com/data/media/206/1_black.jpg" /></a>
```

Basically, with this code, when I open the image, the url will become e.g. www.mysite.com#image1

If I copy that address and paste it on, for example Facebook, obviously it won't give any thumb to share. The correct thumb would be http://freeimagesarchive.com/data/media/206/1_black.jpg but the idea is not to share the image link, but the fancybox link.

I hope I made myself clear, sorry for the english.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want Facebook to share this image properly, you need a page for each image, with the proper [Open Graph meta tags](http://ogp.me/) on it. These will have to be either hard-coded in static files, or generated dynamically by a server-side script. These pages will be the URLs that you share on Facebook so their [parser](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) can read them.

If you want end users to see the Fancybox version, when they visit the shared URL, you can redirect them with Javascript code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The thing is, I already have a unique url for each image, can't that work this way? Isn't there a way to generate og tags for each ../#image?

Comment: @coldpumpkin I'm following in your footsteps here a couple years later.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @dotcommer No, I haven't :\