# How to make a link to execute a jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a single page with several links opening different fancybox galleries.

Each gallery is "activated" by clicking on a link like the following (in this case for "galleryone"):

```
<a class="manualfancybox" data-gallery="galleryone" name="galleryone" id="galleryone" href="#galleryone">
    <img src="imageToClickToOpenGallery.png" />
</a>
```

Each gallery (in this case "galleryone") is created by the following code:

```
<div id="galleryone">
    <a href="001.jpg" rel="gal_one" class="fancybox" /></a>
    <a href="002.jpg" rel="gal_one" class="fancybox" /></a>
    […]
    <a href="020.jpg" rel="gal_one" class="fancybox" /></a>
</div>
```

When the user clicks "imageToClickToOpenGalleryOne.png" it opens "galleryone" fancybox in fullscreen (thanks again [JFK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055987/jfk). That's ok, that's exactly as it should be.

"Manual Fancybox" uses the following jquery:

```
/* MANUALFANCYBOX by JFK (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055987/jfk) */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".manualfancybox").on("click", function () {
        var gallery = "#" + $(this).data("gallery");
        $(gallery).find(".fancybox").eq(0).click();
        return false;
    });
});
```

QUESTION: How can I make a link, like http://www.mysite.com/#galleryone to open "galleryone" like if the user has accessed my page and clicked on "imageToClickToOpenGalleryOne.png"?

Javascript, jquery, php… .htaccess?? I myself am not being able event to think it, let alone to achieve a solution…

Maybe it's not even possible due to security reasons, but nevertheless I need a solution to share links to my galleries...

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/9030970/1055987? it may need a bit tweaking though

Comment: for a link like this `http://www.mysite.com/#galleryone` you only need to add this to your code : `if(window.location.hash) { $(window.location.hash).trigger('click');  }`. **IMPORTANT** : just make sure you place this **AFTER** the `fancybox()` initialization (or at the end of your `ready()` method).

Comment: Yes, JFK, it DID WORK with this code yaaaayyyyy!!!
The only thing is that, for some reason, it's not showing the gallery background anymore, therefore I can't click anywhere outside the image to close the image window (it does work with "ESC" key though).
But, that response you gave on the other question (stackoverflow.com/a/9030970/1055987) works perfectly. I'll try that then come back.

Comment: JFK, I will not be able to mark your answer as correct because it's in a comment.

Comment: Please, JFK, take a look:
[http://www.oleschmitt.com.br/novo/imagem/](http://www.oleschmitt.com.br/novo/imagem/) and click in any gallery to see how it is/should allways be.


Than try to access:
[http://www.oleschmitt.com.br/novo/imagem/#moda](http://www.oleschmitt.com.br/novo/imagem/#moda)

Comment: Is a hoisting issue, this is why I asked you to place the script AFTER the fancybox init. Try moving the call `<script src="fancybox.min.js>` BEFORE the call `<script src="scripts.js">`

Comment: see my answer for all issues and workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a link like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/#galleryone
```

you only need to add this to your current code :

```
if(window.location.hash) { 
    $(window.location.hash).trigger('click'); 
}
```

**IMPORTANT** : just make sure you place this **AFTER** the `fancybox()` initialization (or at the end of your `ready()` method).

**EDIT** : the OP said :

```
it's working but it's not showing the gallery background anymore, 
therefore I can't click anywhere outside the image 
to close the image window (it does work with "ESC" key though).
```

It seems to be hoisting issue, try placing your script calls in this order :

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery.fancybox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Fancybox should be called **before** the *scripts.js* where you placed the  `$(window.location.hash).trigger('click');` code. Right now *scripts.js* is called first.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the fragment identifier in the url. To get that, use the `window.location.hash` to get everything from the hash symbol on, ex: "http://example.com#foobar" has a `location.hash` of "#foobar". You can check the `[window.onhashchange][1]` event to see if the hash has changed. You can then parse the hash and load whatever you need.

Comment: Funny, the only person who seems to have understood the question got a -1 ??? (most likely the person who down voted this answer didn't understand the question)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same thing JFK. And as nobody seemed to understand my question, I've took a long time uploading my website to my webserver, so people could SEE it.