# Fancybox start on page load by specific link

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've got a working Fancybox that works just I want, except that I want the Fancybox to load when I enter my site by a specific link - in my case a link in an email.

So if the user enters my page no Fancybox will show, but when the user enters the email-link the Fancybox will show. Think of it as a landing page.

Got any ideas?

The Fancybox I use is this one - http://fancyapps.com

Comment: It would be a good idea if you post the code you are using while trying to make fancybox work the way you want

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a direct link to any fancybox box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028310/how-to-create-a-direct-link-to-any-fancybox-box)

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/9030970/1055987

Comment: Thanks JFK, your link worked great for me!

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a separate landing page for those who are emailed the link. Unless maybe you can detect some UserAgent string being passed along with the visitor, but I dont think this would be a very efficient way of doing this.

Comment: You are right with the separate landing page, but I would like to avoid that..
You don't think that anchor points can do the trick?